# Making archive from files with same names in different directories

Tags: bash, archive

I have some files with same names but under different directories. For example, path1/filea, path1/fileb, path2/filea, path2/fileb,....

What is the best way to make the files into an archive? Under these directories, there are many other files under these directories that I don't want to make into the archive. Off the top of my head, I think of using Bash, probably ar, tar and other commands, but am not sure how exactly to do it.

Renaming the files seems to make the file names a little complicated. I tend to keep the directory structure inside the archive. Or I might be wrong. Other ideas are welcome!

Thanks and regards!

---

EDIT:

Examples would be really nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have used to make a tar ball for the files with same name in different directories is

```
$find <path> -name <filename> -exec tar -rvf data.tar '{}' \;

i.e. tar [-]r --append
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Octopus! What does "'{}' \" mean?

Comment: the breakets stores the output of find command and slash semicolon ends the find with exec.  you can look at 'man find' for more details.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `tar` with `--exclude PATTERN` option. See the man page for more.
To exclude files, you can see [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html) for examples.

Comment: Thanks! Would you give some examples?

Answer (score 2):

To recursively copy only files with filename "filea" or "fileb" from /path/to/source to /path/to/archive, you could use:

```
rsync -avm --include='file[ab]' -f 'hide,! */' /path/to/source/ /path/to/archive/
```

- `'*/'` is a pattern which matches 'any directory'

  `'! */'` matches anything which is not a directory (i.e. a file)

  `'hide,! */'` means hide all files

  Filter rules are applied in order, and the first rule that matches is applied.
  `--include='file[ab]'` has precedence, so if a file matches `'file[ab]'`, it is included.
  Any other file gets excluded from the list of files to transfer.

Another alternative is to use the `find...exec` pattern:

```
mkdir /path/to/archive
cd /path/to/source
find . -type f -iname "file[ab]" -exec cp --parents '{}' /path/to/archive ";"
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it work for files coming from several source paths, and they have same names? Also can it maintain the directories inside the archive?

Comment: If you have multiple source paths, my first inclination would be to name /path/to/source/ as the parent directory of all the source paths. However, if the parent has some files named "filea" which you want, and others that you don't then obviously that is not going to give the desired result. In that case, yes, you could issue multiple `rsync` commands with different source paths, but all the same archive path.

And yes, the archive directory maintains the directory structure.

Comment: Simpler:  find <whatever> cpio -pdl <new-directory>
(usually you want the l to just create links).

Answer (score 2):

You may give the find command multiple directories to search through.

```
# example: create archive of .tex files
find -x LaTeX-files1 LaTeX-files2 -name "*.tex" -print0 | tar --null --no-recursion -uf LaTeXfiles.tar --files-from -
```